# How can I map REST entities with my own models

Tags: c#, .net, json, rest, mapping

I have been given a REST service which provides some strange names, see json fomart below.
I have created some classes to map them to JSON using the following line:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SSTR)(jsond).inhoud_b.ToArray();
```

I have created classes such as:

```
Class inhoud_b {...}
Class bidt{...}
etc.
```

Json:

```
{
  "nmbr": 0,
  "tp": 1,
  "sort": {
    "sorted": false,
    "unsorted": true
  },
  "inhoud_b":[
    {
      "bidt": {
        "id": "144a207b-dd48-4ebe-87cb-153e3c6179c4",
        "knldge": null,
        "lTT": null,
        "lD": {
          "id": "52",
          "text": "EM"
        }
      }
    },
{
      "bidt": {
        "id": "155B307b-dd48-4ebe-87cb-125487856579",
        "knldge": null,
        "lTT": null,
        "lDg": {
          "id": "523",
          "text": "AM"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "first": true,
  "totalElements": 2
}
```

My question is, how can I map these entities with my own more meaningful models and use my models in my own code rather than those entities which don't make any sense to other developers?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `JsonPropertyAttribute` to annotate your model properties with their corresponding property name in the JSON - https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm

Comment: thanks for your reply. How do I apply that to the class name as well? Is there an attribute which can be applied to class name?

Comment: The class name can be whatever you want it to be. It uses the property name you give it when you use it in an object so for example - ```public class FriendlyName``` could have all the properties of `bidt`. You would then use this class in an object like - ```public FriendlyName Bidt {get;set;}``` and it'll deserialise the `bidt` object into there